# JQuery Tables Validation

Tags: jquery, html, validation, dynamic-tables

I have a dynamic table setup on my page and am using [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) plugin to validate my entire form. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dCQqQ/2/) is the code for my table.

I don't know why it won't work on fiddle but it works perfectly fine on the site. But the functionality is not the question, I'm wondering how I can use the validation plugin to validate the table inputs.

Comment: Doesn't work on fiddle because you selected MooTools instead of jQuery.  Try this http://jsfiddle.net/dCQqQ/3/ for the functionality.  What validation are you trying to do?

Comment: @Lance I'm not sure I understand your question fully but I want to make sure that all the textboxes in the tables are at least filled for starters.

Answer (score 2):

The validate plugin is based on classes. So to make sure every input has a value, add class="required" to the input.  From there you can add specific types of validation like class="required email" to an email field that will make sure that the email field has a value and that the value is in an acceptable email format.

According to the doc for the plugin you may have problems with field names that are [complex](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29)  like yours.

This should get you started http://jsfiddle.net/dCQqQ/5/